# compatiblity between Asp.net 4.5.2 with Oracle12c

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, oracle12c

I am trying to run a select query in Oracle 12c using ASP.net vb code (Framework - 4.5.2).

It is taking a long time to bind data in datatable.

```
 da.Fill(ds) - fill dataset using dataadapter
```

Initially it was oracle 11g, The same code works fine in that but not in 12C , the performance is very slow.

Below is the time taken when we connect the same code to different server to fetch same 10 records .

- Oracle 11G - 5 seconds
- Oracle 12C - 463 seconds

But if I run the same query directly in both servers (without .NET):

- Oracle 11g -  15 seconds
- Oracle 12C - 4 seconds

This is for fetching the same 10 records, in both cases.

---

Below is the .NET code used:

VB.NET code:

```
oraConn.Open()
da.SelectCommand = myComm
da.Fill(dt)
oraConn.Close()
```

web.config:

```
 <add name="OracleCon" connectionString="SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)));uid=;pwd=;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

Comment: probably a query optimisation issue. Have you executed the same query direct in Oracle (without .NET) to see what happens? But beyond that there's really nothing we can suggest without a lot more specific information.

Comment: Thanks for the response..if i run the same query directly in both server - In oracle 11g ,for fetching 10 records it is 15 seconds , in Oracle12c it is 4 seconds for same 10 records. the time taken was in the vb code which was mentioned earlier. question is do we need to add any additional code to connect Oracle 12c from visual studio 2015?

Comment: Show us the code you've got right now. We don't even know how you're connecting to the database or executing the queries. We don't know if you're using some sort of ORM. We don't know your connection string.  To tell you if you need to change your code we first need to know what it looks like now.

Comment: webconfig:
<connectionStrings><add name="OracleCon" connectionString="SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)));uid=;pwd=;" />
  </connectionStrings>
vb code:
 oraConn.Open()
 da.SelectCommand = myComm
da.Fill(dt)
oraConn.Close()

Comment: Please use your "edit" button to add this to your question, and format it nicely to be clear and readable (as it would appear in visual studio, and as you have no doubt seen in other questions on this site). Code does not belong in comments - it's an important detail of the question, not a secondary remark. Thanks

Comment: thanks its updated in the question. web config tag was not getting saved.

Comment: that's because you need to format your code, as I mentioned earlier. Turn that part into a proper "code block" section, otherwise StackOverflow treats things starting with `<` like a HTML tag, which won't show up. Format the rest of the code too, so it's readable and indented correctly - just like you'd want to see it in your IDE. You can see the formatting options in the toolbar in the question editor. You can get also more help about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks its edited with details and code..

Comment: ok. Some more detail please. 1) What is the contents of `myComm`? It would be useful to know what query you are running. 2) Is the table schema identical in both databases, including indexes, keys etc? 3) Are the database servers on the same machine as your code? Or are they each on different machines? Are the machines located close together physically? I am trying to see if maybe there is a network issue here as well or something. P.S. Strange that 11C is 3 times slower when you query it direct, rather than through .NET. That makes no sense. Are you sure the test conditions were correct?

Comment: both db are same in index , keys and everything. Query is also same. the question now is , any special key in web config is needed to connect or any new way to connect the 12C Server? if the query needs optimization then the performance in 11G should also be slow.

Comment: strange that querying 11G direct was so much slower than querying 11G through .NET though don't you think? That makes me wonder if your test results are really accurate. Have you run the tests repeatedly? Are you getting these same timings consistently? P.S. you didn't answer the question about the location of servers or any possible network differences. AFAIK there is no change needed to the connection details. https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ is always your friend for checking that sort of thing - it does not mention any difference between DB server versions.

Comment: P.P.S. " if the query needs optimization then the performance in 11G should also be slow." ...not necessarily, if the implementation of the underlying DB engine has changed in some relevant way. That's not something we can easily discover without reading release notes etc in a lot of detail. Other factors, as mentioned, could be network latency / load, load on the server, load on the client, relative processing power of the two DB servers (if they are in fact separate machines) etc. Performance problems are tricky to diagnose because there are so many variables.

Comment: That's why, at the very least, you must provide detailed information about the environments, and also ensure you run the tests repeatedly and try to keep all other conditions as stable as possible during them, so that the database itself is the main variable in play.

Comment: P.P.P.S you didn't provide the requested details about the actual query being executed, either. If we ask for information, it's because it might be useful. So it's generally a good idea to respond and provide it. Then we can more easily rule it in or out as a potential factor. Providing the actual query and the actual schema is clearly going to be of interest. Also it would be interesting to know if you experience performance differences between the servers when running any other queries...or is it just this one? have you tested that kind of thing at all?

Comment: instead of using system.data.oracleclient , using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client fixed the performance issue.

Comment: That's great. You should write it as the answer then, not just a comment. The Answers section below is for when you find a solution. And you are allowed to answer your own question, and people are allowed to vote on it. Answers are searchable on google (comments are not), so then other people can benefit from your knowledge :-)

Comment: Thanks,  added  in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `system.data.oracleclient`, using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` fixed the performance issue.

```
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
```

in code. In references add

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
```